# Dynamic application form free flow

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jsp, struts

I am building a product in which customers can create dynamic form depending upon their requirements. For example one customer can create a form having fields like first name, last name, others can have one extra field like middle name.

I want to store each and every customers settings and finally i want to merge these two settings into one form at the time of display to our end users. I am finding right way to implement it.

1. Finding a way to store individual customers settings either in Database or XML or anything.
2. Finding a way to merge customers settings into one form, once our end user select both customers to apply (i want to give only one form which contains both customer form fields).
3. Please remember that i am providing a tool where customer can create new label like Gender, which is not defined in the system. We are giving generin data type to create such fields using text box, text-area, table, check-box, radio and many more.

Please assist me to design the architecture of above problem set.

Comment: If I understood it correctly you are trying to create app which will create dynamic forms based on the user's preferences , is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modelling your database as [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). See this :

- [Using Database Metadata and its Semantics to Generate Automatic and Dynamic Web Entry Forms](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCECS2007/WCECS2007_pp654-658.pdf)
- [Planning and Implementing a Metadata-Driven Digital Repository](http://scholarspace.manoa.hawaii.edu/bitstream/handle/10125/337/0409CCQPlanningImplementing.pdf?sequence=1)

You can also find useful threads here in SO in the tag: [eav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eav)